# powershell How to get last Function App Run History

Tags: azure, powershell

I have this following line where I want to find if there wasn't any runs for more than x days. How to check only last Logic App run?

```
Get-AzLogicAppRunHistory -ResourceGroupName test -Name testName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Group-Object` to group the entries by app, then select the latest `EndTime` in each group, here shown using `Select-Object` with [a calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties):

```
$RunHistoryPerLogicApp = Get-AzLogicAppRunHistory -ResourceGroupName test-Name testName |Group-Object LogicAppName

$RunHistoryPerLogicApp |Select-Object Name,@{Name='LastRunEndTime';Expression={$_.Group |Sort-Object EndTime |Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty EndTime}}
```

Comment: @IvanK I'm afraid I don't understand your question - how will you compare it if it doesn't exist? :)

Comment: @IvanK `... |Where-Object {$_.LastRunEndTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)}`

Comment: Yes - by using the approach in my last comment. Using `Where-Object` will give you the whole object, not just the value that was compared

Comment: Is there possible to add to this check also Logic App that have no runs at all? `|Where-Object {$_.LastRunEndTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)}`